# share git rep access on unix machine with ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, git, acl

at my school we have a student unix server with our accounts.

i have installed git on my account, created a repository, and created the acl permissions on the folder repository so other users can access the repository

```
# file: tp1
# owner: my_account
# group: groupxxx
user::rwx
user:friend_account:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:friend_account:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

but friend_account cant even cd to my tp1 directory (permission denied), so i think the problem should be in unix acl permissions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user needs to be able to `cd` to every directory above `tp1` as well, i.e. `friend_account` must have the `x` permission to every directory above `tp1`. So for example if `tp1` is `/home/daniel/course1/tp1` then you need

```
setfacl -m user:friend_account:x /home/daniel /home/daniel/course1
```

If you give `x` permission but not `r` on a directory, your friend will be able to traverse the directory and reach its subdirectories and access any file that (s)he has permission to, but not view the list of files in the directory.